# is g_timeout_add thread-safe (Linux, GTK3, X11)?

Tags: linux, multithreading, gtk, glib

**Context:** on Linux/Debian/Sid x86-64 for my [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) (GPLv3+) software (described [here](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf))
(GTK 3.24, Glib 2.62, Xorg server, function `register_gui_postponed_BM`, [file `gui_GTKBM.c`](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/gui_GTKBM.c#L5133))

### Question:

**Can `g_timeout_add` be safely called from some other thread than the main thread?** I can easily ensure that call would be serialized (using a pthread mutex) but I cannot guarantee it would be called from the main thread. The threads are Pthreads, not Glib threads.

I found both [this](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) and [that](https://gtk.developpez.com/doc/en/gdk/gdk-Threads.html), and they make me think it is indeed safe.... But I might have understood wrongly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It [boils down to a call](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/2e9b2761d673c0efd477d83a0f0796966abf58f1/glib/gmain.c#L4793) to [`g_source_attach()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-attach), which [locks the `GMainContext`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/2e9b2761d673c0efd477d83a0f0796966abf58f1/glib/gmain.c#L1189) it adds the timeout source to.